ggplot2 legend.position error in vertexai
I am trying to create plots using ggplot2 but the legend is not showing up. I have tried using the scale_fill_manual() argument but I get an error. Below is a sample of the code with and without the scale_fill_manual() code and the outcomes.
ggplot() +
geom_line(obs.ushe.after.move, mapping = aes(x= obs, y = med_wage_diff), col = '#0054E5', linewidth =1.1) + 
geom_line(obs.ushe.after.stayer, mapping = aes(x= obs, y = med_wage_diff), col = '#E5B300', linewidth =1.1) + 
geom_line(obs.ushe.after.non, mapping = aes(x= obs, y = med_wage_diff), col = '#595959', linewidth =1.1) +   

scale_fill_manual(#values =c(colors),
                               #'y4'='#99BEFF', 'y5'= '#FFE599', 'y6'='#AEACAC'),
                     name = "",
                     labels = c('Job-to-Job', 
                                'Job Stayers',
                                'Nonemployed-to-Employed')) +
#  legend('topleft', legend = c(0,1)) +
#  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c('16Q1', '17Q1', '18Q1', '19Q1', '20Q1', '21Q1')) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 20000), labels = scales::dollar) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),  legend.text =element_text(size=14)) +
  labs(y = '', x = '')


Below is the code and error when using the "legend.position```
ggplot() +
geom_line(obs.ushe.after.move, mapping = aes(x= obs, y = med_wage_diff), col = '#0054E5', linewidth =1.1) + 
geom_line(obs.ushe.after.stayer, mapping = aes(x= obs, y = med_wage_diff), col = '#E5B300', linewidth =1.1) + 
geom_line(obs.ushe.after.non, mapping = aes(x= obs, y = med_wage_diff), col = '#595959', linewidth =1.1) +   

scale_fill_manual(#values =c(colors),
                               #'y4'='#99BEFF', 'y5'= '#FFE599', 'y6'='#AEACAC'),
                     name = "",
                     labels = c('Job-to-Job', 
                                'Job Stayers',
                                'Nonemployed-to-Employed')) +
#  legend('topleft', legend = c(0,1)) +
#  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c('16Q1', '17Q1', '18Q1', '19Q1', '20Q1', '21Q1')) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 20000), labels = scales::dollar) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),  legend.text =element_text(size=14)) +
  labs(y = '', x = '') +
 legend.position = c('bottom')

Error: Error in ggplot() + geom_line(obs.ushe.after.move, mapping = aes(x = obs, : invalid (NULL) left side of assignment Traceback:
Below is a sample of the data.
result  obs med_wage_diff
<chr>   <int>   <int>
mover   0   860
mover   1   1533
mover   2   1192
mover   3   698
mover   4   715
mover   5   597
mover   6   661
mover   7   542
mover   8   632
mover   9   632
mover   10  616


It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

This said: You have to put legend.position inside theme(). But to get a legend you have so map on aesthetics. See Add legend to ggplot2 line plot.

I included a sample of the data for one of the dataframes. I only went to 10 observations.

Also, I added legend.position inside theme() but I still got an error. The theme() code now looks like this: theme(legend.position = 'bottom', panel.background = element_blank(),  legend.text =element_text(size=14)) with the error saying: Error in ggplot() + geom_line(obs.ushe.after.move, mapping = aes(x = obs, : invalid (NULL) left side of assignment Traceback:

I was able to generate the plot with the code, however, the legend is still not appearing
